# Raspberry Pi 4 - hwclock DS3231 RTC delay at boot

Tags: gpio, pi-4, i2c, rtc

Running a Raspberry Pi 4 with a DS3231 RTC setup.
Everything is setup correctly and working fine and the hwclock is synced correctly.

The unit is running without any internet connection.

The problem is at boot running date command or hwclock -r reads the incorrect time (2000-01-01 11:00...) for approx 30-45seconds and then will automatically go back to reading the correct (and synced time).

Any ideas on what is causing this or how to get the correct time to be read straight away?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for needing the correct time straight away?

Comment: You claim everything is setup correctly so it must work. If not what you have done (which you haven't explained) is not.